# Ошибка Stack around the variable 'Y' was corrupted в С++

Tags: c++, массивы

Вот задание: Вычислить 12 значений функции
y = ax^2 + bx + c на отрезке [e,f], сохранить их в массиве Y и определить, является ли функция нисходящей, растущей или немонотонной на этом отрезке.
Моя реализация:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double input_failsafe(const char cout_string[] = "") 
{
    double out;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << cout_string;
        cin >> out;
        if (cin.fail()) 
        {
            cout << "Wrong input" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
        }
        else
        {
            cin.ignore(32767, '\n'); 
            return out;
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    
    cout << "Task 1" << endl;
    cout << "1D Array" << endl;
    double x, y, a, b, c, e, f, step;
    const int n = 12;
    bool pos = false, neg = false;
    double Y[n];
    a = input_failsafe("Print a: ");
    b = input_failsafe("Print b: ");
    c = input_failsafe("Print c: ");
    e = input_failsafe("Print e: ");
    f = input_failsafe("Print f: ");
    if (f <= e)
    {
        do {
            cout << "Wrong input. f must be greater than e\n";
            f = input_failsafe("Print f: ");
        } while (f <= e);
    }

    step = (f - e) / 12;
    x = e;
    cout << "\ny = ax^2 + bx + c  " << "range [" << e << ";" << f << "]\n\n" << "Array Y: \n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n, x < f; i++)
    {
        y = a * pow(x, 2) + b * x + c;
        Y[i] = y;
        cout << Y[i] << " ";
        x += step;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        if (Y[i] < Y[i + 1])
        {
            pos = true;
        }
        if (Y[i] > Y[i + 1])
        {
            neg = true;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\nFunction:";
    if (pos && neg)
    {
        cout << "\nThe function is not monotonous" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (pos)
        {
            cout << "\nIncreasing function" << endl;
        }
        if (neg)
        {
            cout << "\nDecreasing function" << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Суть проблемы:
Вроде бы код рабочий, но если ввести какие-то определенные значения(как на скриншоте(я ввел отрезок [1;15])), то компилятор выдаст ошибку Stack around the variable 'Y' was corrupted, а программа выведет не 12, как было нужно, а 13 значений.
[image: Stack around the variable 'Y' was corrupted.]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В текущем виде виде Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен, пожалуйста, конкретизируйте

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `i < n, x < f` проверяет только второе из двух условий, используйте `&&` вместо `,`.

Comment: Если не секрет... Вижу уже второй вопрос, в котором используют `cin.ignore(32767, '\n');`. Почему именно это число? Чтобы пропускать до упора, там должно быть `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Долго писать :) А кто-то из лекторов в каком-то вузе до сих пор считает, что `int` — это 2 байта...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь

```
for (int i = 0; i < n, x < f; i++)
```

у вас использован оператор запятая, т.е. условие `i<n` игнорируется, и работает только условие `x < f`. Но при работе с числами с плаваящей запятой специфика их представления в памяти с ограниченной точностью запросто может привести к тому, что у вас будет не `n`, а `n+1` итерация и вы выйдете за границы массива. Не при всех значениях, как вы сами заметили.

И еще вот это

```
y = a * pow(x, 2) + b * x + c;
```

лучше переписать как

```
y = (a*x + b)*x + c;
```